# Inherited Methods How do I make super methods available?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, mysql-python, pymysql

I have a class (which works [or appears to]) to run an sql query. Code is below. If I inherit from object and do not use super, it works fine.

I am learning about inserting methods from super classes and so I thought that I would make my class header look like this

```
class database_connector(Connection)
```

and incorporate a super call in **init** like this

```
super().__init__()
```

However, I get

```
TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

I tried

```
super(database_connector, self).__init__()
```

after reading some other stuff in StackOverFlow but I now still get

```
TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

I am anticipating that this work will allow me to call more methods from pymysql.Connection.

Here is my class

```
from pymysql import Connection

#        set up default values for database connector


class database_connector(Connection):
    def __init__(self, host=None, db=None, user=None, passwd=None):
        super(database_connector, self).__init__()
        if host is None:
            self.host = "mysql_host_ip"
        else:
            self.host = host
        if db is None:
            self.db = "fred_db"
        else:
            self.db = db
        if user is None:
            self.user = "fred"
        else:
            self.user = user
        if passwd is None:
            self.passwd = "fredspasswd"
        else:
            self.passwd = passwd

        self.this_database = (Connection(host=self.host,
                                         user=self.user,
                                         passwd=self.passwd,
                                         db=self.db))
        self.cur = self.this_database.cursor()

def my_sql_run_this_sql(self, sql_to_run=None):
    if sql_to_run is None:
        data = self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM person")
    else:
        data = self.cur.execute(sql_to_run)
    data = []
    for row in self.cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row)
    self.this_database.close()
    return data
```

Comment: I needed a bit of reformatting to get the thing to look right but I am now there.

Comment: Why are you calling the super method? Which attributes are you trying to inherit from the parent? Because after .__init__() you have no attributes.

Comment: `pymysql.Connection` is a function that returns a `pymysql.connections.Connection` object. Try `class database_connector(pymysql.connections.Connection):`

Comment: @ Simeon Ikudabo I have not got particular methods in mind. I am learning about inherited methods. However I have got the format from Python 3 docs and there is no mention of needing to predict all the calls that might be made ahead of time. If Im am using OO re-usability, I should be able to call parent methods that have not yet been added to Connection.

Comment: Come to think about it, __init__ super should need no args anyway. Have you got an example ?

Comment: Your class is not a Connection but rather has a Connection. It shouldn't be a subclass.

Comment: Ah, thank you DanD! Good  point. Maybe I should call the class a MySql _query_runner or something like that. That being said,  could I inherit from pymysql?